# How to handle XCM encoding and building in JavaScript

Tags: xcm, javascript

Talisman and I are looking into building a simple JS module that helps developers build XCM for transactions and abstract common patterns like cross chain transfers into a simple JS function taking inputs like: `fromParachain, toParachain, assetId, recipient etc.` These functions would then return the XCM object and allow the developer to encode it into hex so that it can be submitted to the network via the `submitExtrinsic` call.

I am currently working on an example transfer which would allow a user to transfer an asset from one parachain to another. You can see it here: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fbasilisk-rpc.dwellir.com#/extrinsics/decode/0x34030208000400010200e12e0500000b00e057eb481b0e010004010100411f081300010200e12e050000070010a5d4e80107001c040a5d0d010004000101008eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a48001c040a5d000000

However, I am running into the following difficulties:

- How does one encode the XCM into hex? I know that this is possible as it is done on the web interface but there is very little insight into how this is actually done in practice. I have tried looking through the web portal's code but it is so abstract. I want to be able to build and encode the XCM I have in the above link.
- XCM itself is not parsable in JavaScript, it looks like JSON but it isn’t. I am struggling to understand how we can formulate such a simple XCM message in JavaScript and then encode it into hex so it can be submitted as a transaction. I know that it is using something called SCALE but I am at a loss as to how to use it and import the types available in XCM v2.

I am also curious to hear from developers as to whether they believe such a module would be useful for them. I know that it is currently very difficult to make an XCM transaction in polkadot.js so I imagine this would be a very important piece of infrastructure.

Please help.

UPDATE:

I am trying to encode my XCM message by doing the following (using the `WithdrawAsset` section as an example):

1. Convert the XCM into JSON `const data = {"WithdrawAsset":[{"id":{[...]},"fun":{[...]}}]}`
2. Define the SCALE codec object
   `const withdrawAssetCodec = scale.object(["WithdrawAsset", scale.array(idCodex, fungibleCodex)]);`
3. Encode with data
   `const encoded = withdrawAssetCodec.encode(data);`
4. Grab the hex string representation of the data and submit it via `api.rpc.author.submitAndWatchExtrinsic('0x' + Buffer.from(encoded).toString('hex'));`

I have hacked something together here, with the steps above: https://github.com/James-Sangalli/xcm-module-sample/blob/master/index.js#L153

Further questions:

1. If we have to represent the XCM as JSON to use the scale codec library, why isn't XCM represented as JSON? Why use a totally new format? Are we safe in assuming that this XCM:
   `interior: { X2: [ { Parachain: 3,000 } { GeneralIndex: 0 } ] } }` can be represented as this: `"interior": { "X2": [ { "Parachain": 3000 }, { "GeneralIndex": 0 } ] }`, in JSON?
2. How do we encode the call function signature into this XCM call? In this instance it is `polkadotXcm.execute(message, maxWeight)` and I noticed that in my link above, the first two bytes `3403` are a call index which tells the polkadot portal I am using the `polkadotXcm.execute` function.

Many of the types used in my XCM sample are not defined in the codec library, but Rob has referenced capi and there are such types defined here: https://github.com/paritytech/capi/issues/241.

It would be great if someone could include an example of a transaction that shows how we get from an XCM message to an encoded transaction that can be submitted to the network.

Answer (score 2):

XCM messages are simply SCALE-encoded according to their specification.

SCALE is a binary encoding format which is described here: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/scale-codec/

You can use the TypeScript scale library by ParityTech here: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec-ts

There are some examples I'll copy from the repo on encoding and decoding:

```typescript
import * as $ from "https://deno.land/x/scale/mod.ts";

const $person = $.object(
  ["name", $.str],
  ["nickName", $.str],
  ["superPower", $.option($.str)],
);

const valueToEncode = {
  name: "Magdalena",
  nickName: "Magz",
  superPower: "Hydrokinesis",
};

const encodedBytes: Uint8Array = $person.encode(valueToEncode);
const decodedValue: Person = $person.decode(encodedBytes);

assertEquals(decodedValue, valueToEncode);
```

Encoded objects have the type `Uint8Array` which can be converted into hex easily. There are a variety of answers to the question of converting byte arrays to hex strings here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225161/convert-uint8array-into-hex-string-equivalent-in-node-js .

Comment: You may find `capi`, which builds on top of this SCALE stack, useful. It exposes type definitions for many common types in Substrate blockchains. https://github.com/paritytech/capi