# How to encode an extrinsic for RPC from a web client?

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, rpc, api, metadata

I need to programmatically pack an extrinsic for an RPC, I believe I'm looking for the following front-end functionality:

- extract relevant indices from the Metadata
- fill the extrinsic parameters
- properly Scale/hex encode it, be it signed or unsigned
  exactly as PolkadotJS app does.
  Something like this Rust code, but for the front-end:
  https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-interaction-examples-rs/blob/main/src/bin/05_transfer_balance.rs

Please could anyone  indicate me relevant packages in the PolkadotJS sources that do the job, maybe some code snippets that demonstrate the codification routine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the library you want to use [txwrapper-core](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core), is a set of  tools to quickly create, test, and maintain a library of helper functions for offline transaction generation with your chain.

An example you can use as a reference about how to use it is here: https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/blob/main/packages/txwrapper-examples/polkadot/src/polkadot.ts

First it gets the metadata with `state_getMetadata`, with this creates the Polkadot's type registry and then it construct the extrinsic with the help of the library `@substrate/txwrapper-polkadot`. The example also shows you how to generate the signed extrinsic and how to send it to the node within the RPC `author_submitExtrinsic`.

Another option to encode/decode SCALE with typescript is the library [parity-scale-codec-ts](https://github.com/paritytech/scale-ts). You can see an example of how to use it in this previous StackExchange answer: [How to handle XCM encoding and building in JavaScript](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4977/2762)